# Camera images not deleted after captured in android actual device

Tags: android, file, path, camera, capture

I am deleting all the images from the DCIM(CAMERA) directory after capturing images by getting path for the particular image.

It works fine while i am testing my app in Genymotion. But, When I tried it in android devices i.e. samsung s3 as well as in XOLO_a500s it did not deleting images captured.

What might be the Problem ?

**Code to delete :**

```
public void deleteCapturedImages() {
    alCapturedImagesPath = mDBHelper.getCapturedImagesPath();
    if (alCapturedImagesPath.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < alCapturedImagesPath.size(); i++) {
            File f = new File(alCapturedImagesPath.get(i));
            f.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

**Permissions in Manifest :**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**For that :**

I am taking path of image captured, from the `onActivityResult()` of Camera and saving it to the database.

Now, At the time of deleting image, i am retrieving that path from database and converting it to File using `new File(databasePath);` as done in function `deleteCapturedImages()`.

Comment: Have you set the appropriate permissions? WHat is your code for deleting files and what is your Manifest file?

Comment: yes, posting my stuff...

Comment: I think it issue of path. Can you put a toast of check if the path returned is actually where your images are?

Comment: Paths is good on the device as well?

Comment: yes, getting different path(image saved wtith different name).